# Is there a more efficient way to import / export modules in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module, export

Is there a more efficient - less code - way to do these import and export operations?
The imported modules are all exported as `default`.

```
import TemplateInactive from './TemplateInactive'
import TemplateRegular from './TemplateRegular'
import TemplateSemiUrgent from './TemplateSemiUrgent'
import TemplateUrgent from './TemplateUrgent'

export {
  TemplateInactive,
  TemplateRegular,
  TemplateSemiUrgent,
  TemplateUrgent,
}
```

thanks

Comment: Faster how? Less code? Less execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

```js
export { default as TemplateInactive } from './TemplateInactive'
export { default as TemplateRegular } from './TemplateRegular'
export { default as TemplateSemiUrgent } from './TemplateSemiUrgent'
export { default as TemplateUrgent } from './TemplateUrgent'
```

Comment: Installing `'@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from'` made the trick with your code, thanks!